# Swapping two variable value without using third variable

Tags: c++

One of the very tricky questions asked in an interview.

Swap the values of two variables like `a=10` and `b=15`.

Generally to swap two variables values, we need 3rd variable like:

```
temp=a;
a=b;
b=temp;
```

Now the requirement is, swap values of two variables without using 3rd variable.

Comment: Wow. A poorly chosen interview question IMHO. This is a technique that's rarely, if ever, useful in practice. There's a good chance that it will only confuse the compiler's optimizer resulting in less efficient code than a "temporary swap". Unless this place you were interviewing at gets involved in very math-heavy stuff (think: encryption algorithm development or the like) I can't imagine any good reason to ask such a question.

Comment: Indeed, that question doesn't tell you anything other than whether the candidate knows this particular trick that is pretty much useless in production code. I suppose you might run across the occasional wizard who figures it out on the fly, but people like that who don't already know the trick are likely to be pretty rare.

Comment: May-be they want to weed out people who think knowing such tricks is what makes good programmer? Also, when reading about the xor-trick, pay attention to when it will fail (which IMO makes it pretty much completely useless for general-purpose integer swapping).

Answer (score 162, accepted):

Using the [xor swap algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XOR_swap_algorithm)

```
void xorSwap (int* x, int* y) {
    if (x != y) { //ensure that memory locations are different
       *x ^= *y;
       *y ^= *x;
       *x ^= *y;
    }
}
```

**Why the test?**

The test is to ensure that x and y have different memory locations (rather than different values). This is because `(p xor p) = 0` and if both x and y share the same memory location, when one is set to 0, both are set to 0.
When both *x and *y are 0, all other xor operations on *x and *y will equal 0 (as they are the same), which means that the function will set both *x and *y set to 0.

If they have the same values but not the same memory location, everything works as expected

```
*x = 0011
*y = 0011
//Note, x and y do not share an address. x != y

*x = *x xor *y  //*x = 0011 xor 0011
//So *x is 0000

*y = *x xor *y  //*y = 0000 xor 0011
//So *y is 0011

*x = *x xor *y  //*x = 0000 xor 0011
//So *x is 0011
```

**Should this be used?**

In general cases, no. The compiler will optimize away the temporary variable and given that swapping is a common procedure it should output the optimum machine code for your platform.

Take for example this quick test program written in C.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

#define USE_XOR 

void xorSwap(int* x, int *y){
    if ( x != y ){
        *x ^= *y;
        *y ^= *x;
        *x ^= *y;
    }
}

void tempSwap(int* x, int* y){
    int t;
    t = *y;
    *y = *x;
    *x = t;
}


int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
    int x = 4;
    int y = 5;
    int z = pow(2,28); 
    while ( z-- ){
#       ifdef USE_XOR
            xorSwap(&x,&y);
#       else
            tempSwap(&x, &y);
#       endif
    }
    return x + y;    
}
```

Compiled using:

```
gcc -Os main.c -o swap
```

The xor version takes

```
real    0m2.068s
user    0m2.048s
sys  0m0.000s
```

Where as the version with the temporary variable takes:

```
real    0m0.543s
user    0m0.540s
sys  0m0.000s
```

Comment: Might be worth explaining the why of the test (i.e. that the triple xor approach fails horribly if x and y reference the same object).

Comment: I don't know how this got so many upvotes when the code is so broken.  Both swaps in the tested code segment are completely incorrect. Look close.

Comment: @SoapBox:  Very good point!  The XOR swap zeros x & leaves y untouched, and the temp swap leaves both with the value of x.  Whoops!

Comment: @SoapBox Good catch. Fixed and re-tested and I don't get any major difference in the timings.

Comment: The questioner said two variables, not ints. :P

Answer (score 95):

the general form is:

```
A = A operation B
B = A inverse-operation B
A = A inverse-operation B
```

however you have to potentially watch out for overflows and also not all operations have an inverse that is well defined for all values that the operation is defined. e.g. * and / work until A or B is 0

xor is particularly pleasing as it is defined for all ints and is its own inverse

Comment: XOR(X, X) == 0, so xor works for ints EXCEPT when the two values being swapped are equal.  I'm not the first to point this out and too many have said it (here and elsewhere) to single anyone out for credit.

Answer (score 88):

```
a = a + b
b = a - b // b = a
a = a - b
```

Comment: @Alok: That's not taken in considerations, thus it's impractical :)

Comment: If a and b are of the same, basic, sized integer types (like `int`, `unsigned short`, ...), it still works out in the end, even with overflow, because if a + b overflows, then a - b will underflow.  With these basic integer types, the values just rollover.

Comment: In C, using this on `unsigned` integer types is OK and works always. On signed types, it would invoke undefined behaviour on overflow.

Comment: As long as the variables are the same size and stored in 2's complement form, it works regardless of overflow. The reason is, overflow and underflow means that you are operating congruent modulo 2^b (where b is the number of bits, say 32). Mathematically this gives you the right result. Since the final answer fits in `a` and `b`, and there is only one representation of the number (congruent modulo 2^n) in the range of their type (say int), the overflows and underflows happen in such a way that the end result would be correct.

Comment: @Shahbaz “overflow and underflow means that you are operating congruent modulo 2^b” No, signed overflow in C is undefined behavior. If modulo 2^b results were guaranteed, `gcc -O2` would not optimize `int f(int x) { return (x+1)>x; }` into `return 1;`.

Comment: @Shahbaz: Even if signed integers are *stored* in 2's-complement, the behavior on overflow is still undefined.

Comment: @Shahbaz: My quibble is with the first sentence of that comment. Signed overflow isn't undefined behavior "because the running architecture may not be using 2's complement". It's undefined behavior *because the standard says so*. In particular, it's UB regardless of the representation used for signed integers. Even on the hardware level, a CPU could in principle use a 2's-complement representation for signed integers *and* trap on overflow.

Comment: @KeithThompson, let me rephrase: I believe the standard decided to make signed integer overflow because there are various ways to present them; enforcing a certain presentation makes it incompatible with other architectures which is not in the spirit of C.

Comment: @KeithThompson, It's good to know what's stated as undefined behavior in the standard, but it helps when you understand why it was stated as undefined behavior in the first place. That was what my first sentence was trying to explain.

Comment: I would fire immediately someone writing code like this and not using std::swap . This is a maintenability nightmare

Comment: @Dinaiz `std::swap` isn't available for everyone (e.g. legacy projects on obscure hardware), but you're right, even when writing the swap manually, the final result should be much better.

Comment: This is the best answer if the question is asked in a job interview. (Of course, *where else* would you need to find the answer to this question?)

Answer (score 83):

No-one has suggested using `std::swap`, yet.

```
std::swap(a, b);
```

*I* don't use any temporary variables and depending on the type of `a` and `b` the implementation may have a specalization that doesn't either. The implementation should be written knowing whether a 'trick' is appropriate or not. There's no point in trying to second guess.

More generally, I'd probably want to do something like this, as it would work for class types enabling ADL to find a better overload if possible.

```
using std::swap;
swap(a, b);
```

Of course, the interviewer's reaction to this answer might say a lot about the vacancy.

Comment: of course in C++0x swap will use rvalue references so will be even better!

Comment: Everyone wants to show off the shiny xor or other trick they learned, with various caveats about how to use it, but this indubitably is the best answer.

Comment: why not std::swap(a, b); ? I mean why the using ?

Comment: @Dinaiz without the `std::`, user-defined `swap` implementations for user-defined types are also available to call  (this is what is meant by "it would work for class types enabling ADL to find a better overload if possible").

Comment: `std::swap` uses additional temporary memory in its implementation no? http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/utility/swap/

Comment: "Of course, the interviewer's reaction to this answer might say a lot about the vacancy."

Answer (score 19):

As already noted by manu, XOR algorithm is a popular one which works for all integer values (that includes pointers then, with some luck and casting). For the sake of completeness I would like to mention another less powerful algorithm with addition/subtraction:

```
A = A + B
B = A - B
A = A - B
```

Here you have to be careful of overflows/underflows, but otherwise it works just as fine. You might even try this on floats/doubles in the case XOR isn't allowed on those.

Comment: "*all integer values (that includes pointers then)*" -- What? No, pointers are not integers, and you cannot xor pointer values. You also can't xor floating-point values. But the addition/subtraction method has undefined behavior (for signed or floating-point types) on overflow or underflow, can lose precision for floating-point, and cannot be applied to pointers or other non-numeric types.

Comment: @KeithThompson - OK, loss of precision for floating points is true, but depending on the circumstances, it could be acceptable. As for the pointers - well, I've never heard of a compiler/platform where pointers couldn't be freely cast to integers and back again (taking care to choose an integer of the right size, of course). But then, I'm not a C/C++ expert. I know it goes against the standard, but I was under the impression that this behavior is pretty consistent across... everything.

Comment: @Vilx-: Why would loss of precision be acceptable when it's so easy to avoid it by using a temporary variable -- or `std::swap()`? Sure, you can *convert* pointers to integers and back again (assuming there's a large enough integer type, which isn't guaranteed), but that's not what you suggested; you implied that pointers *are* integers, not that they can be converted to integers. Yes, the accepted answer won't work for pointers. [Charles Bailey's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1841718/827263) using `std::swap` is really the only correct one.

Comment: First of all, the question was "how to swap without using a third variable" and the reason given for that was "an interview question". I just gave one other possible answer. Second, OK, my apologies for implying that pointers are integers. I updated the answer to be hopefully more explicit and correct. Please correct me if I'm still wrong (or update the answer yourself). Third, I deleted the part about the accepted answer. It's not using pointer-to-integer casts anywhere and it works correctly (as far as I understand).

Comment: @KeithThompson: The question could be amended to be about how `std::swap` can be implemented without using a third variable.

Comment: With respect to "never saw a platform where pointers couldn't be cast to integer", this would be true for 8086/8088 and any other platform that uses SEGMENT:OFFSET memory addressing.

Comment: @user3450148 - Well, technically yes... then again, in such systems you most often work just within a single segment, so this technique still works. And for "far" pointers - aren't they also integers, simply twice as wide?

Answer (score 10):

Stupid questions deserve appropriate answers:

```
void sw2ap(int& a, int& b) {
  register int temp = a; // !
  a = b;
  b = temp;
}
```

The only good use of the `register` keyword.

Comment: Is an object declared with storage-class register not a "variable"? Also I'm not convinced this is a good use of register, since if your compiler can't optimise this already then what's the point of even trying, you should either accept whatever rubbish you get or write the assembly yourself ;-) But as you say, a dodgy question deserves a dodgy answer.

Comment: Pretty much all modern compilers ignore the register storage class, as they have a much better idea of what gets frequently accessed than you do.

Comment: Note that this answer is intended for interview(er)s, not compilers. It especially takes advantage of the fact that the kind of interviewers who ask this kind of question don't really understand C++. So, they cannot reject this answer. (and there is no Standard answer; ISO C++ talks about objects not variables).

Comment: Ah, I get you. I was looking in the C standard for mention of variable as a noun, and not just meaning non-const. I found one in n1124, in the section on for loops defining the scope of "variables" declared in the initialiser. Then I realised the question was C++, and didn't bother searching to see if C++ had made the same typo anywhere.

Answer (score 3):

Swapping two numbers using third variable be like this,

```
int temp;
int a=10;
int b=20;
temp = a;
a = b;
b = temp;
printf ("Value of a", %a);
printf ("Value of b", %b);
```

Swapping two numbers without using third variable

```
int a = 10;
int b = 20;
a = a+b;
b = a-b;
a = a-b;
printf ("value of a=", %a);
printf ("value of b=", %b);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
#include<iostream.h>
#include<conio.h>
void main()
{
int a,b;
clrscr();
cout<<"\n==========Vikas==========";
cout<<"\n\nEnter the two no=:";
cin>>a>>b;
cout<<"\na"<<a<<"\nb"<<b;
a=a+b;
b=a-b;
a=a-b;

cout<<"\n\na="<<a<<"\nb="<<b;
getch();
}
```

Comment: After `cout << "Enter the two no=:"` I was expecting to read `cout << "Now enter the two no in  reverse order:"`

Comment: As with several other answers, this has undefined behavior if `a+b` or `a-b` overflows. Also, `void main()` is invalid and `<conio.h>` is non-standard.

Answer (score 2):

Let's see a simple c example to swap two numbers without using the third variable.

**program 1:**

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
main()
{
int a=10, b=20;
clrscr();
printf("Before swap a=%d b=%d",a,b);
a=a+b;//a=30 (10+20)
b=a-b;//b=10 (30-20)
a=a-b;//a=20 (30-10)
printf("\nAfter swap a=%d b=%d",a,b);
getch();
}
```

**Output:**

Before swap a=10 b=20
After swap a=20 b=10

**Program 2: Using * and /**

Let's see another example to swap two numbers using * and /.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
main()
{
int a=10, b=20;
clrscr();
printf("Before swap a=%d b=%d",a,b);
a=a*b;//a=200 (10*20)
b=a/b;//b=10 (200/20)
a=a/b;//a=20 (200/10)
printf("\nAfter swap a=%d b=%d",a,b);
getch();
}
```

**Output:**

Before swap a=10 b=20
After swap a=20 b=10

**Program 3: Making use of bitwise XOR operator:**

The bitwise XOR operator can be used to swap two variables. The XOR of two numbers x and y returns a number which has all the bits as 1 wherever bits of x and y differ. For example, XOR of 10 (In Binary 1010) and 5 (In Binary 0101) is 1111 and XOR of 7 (0111) and 5 (0101) is (0010).

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
 int x = 10, y = 5;
 // Code to swap 'x' (1010) and 'y' (0101)
 x = x ^ y;  // x now becomes 15 (1111)
 y = x ^ y;  // y becomes 10 (1010)
 x = x ^ y;  // x becomes 5 (0101)
 printf("After Swapping: x = %d, y = %d", x, y);
 return 0;
```

**Output:**

After Swapping: x = 5, y = 10

**Program 4:**

No-one has suggested using std::swap, yet.

```
std::swap(a, b);
```

I don't use any temporary variables and depending on the type of a and b the implementation may have a specialization that doesn't either. The implementation should be written knowing whether a 'trick' is appropriate or not.

**Problems with above methods:**

1) The multiplication and division based approach doesn’ work if one of the numbers is 0 as the product becomes 0 irrespective of the other number.

2) Both Arithmetic solutions may cause arithmetic overflow. If x and y are too large, addition and multiplication may go out of integer range.

3) When we use pointers to a variable and make a function swap, all of the above methods fail when both pointers point to the same variable. Let’s take a look what will happen in this case if both are pointing to the same variable.

// Bitwise XOR based method

```
x = x ^ x; // x becomes 0
x = x ^ x; // x remains 0
x = x ^ x; // x remains 0
```

// Arithmetic based method

```
x = x + x; // x becomes 2x
x = x – x; // x becomes 0
x = x – x; // x remains 0
```

Let us see the following program.

```
#include <stdio.h>
void swap(int *xp, int *yp)
{
    *xp = *xp ^ *yp;
    *yp = *xp ^ *yp;
    *xp = *xp ^ *yp;
}

int main()
{
  int x = 10;
  swap(&x, &x);
  printf("After swap(&x, &x): x = %d", x);
  return 0;
}
```

**Output**:

After swap(&x, &x): x = 0

Swapping a variable with itself may be needed in many standard algorithms. For example, see this implementation of QuickSort where we may swap a variable with itself. The above problem can be avoided by putting a condition before the swapping.

```
#include <stdio.h>
void swap(int *xp, int *yp)
{
    if (xp == yp) // Check if the two addresses are same
      return;
    *xp = *xp + *yp;
    *yp = *xp - *yp;
    *xp = *xp - *yp;
}
int main()
{
  int x = 10;
  swap(&x, &x);
  printf("After swap(&x, &x): x = %d", x);
  return 0;
}
```

**Output**:

After swap(&x, &x): x = 10

Answer (score 2):

Of course, the C++ answer should be `std::swap`.

However, there is also no third variable in the following implementation of `swap`:

```
template <typename T>
void swap (T &a, T &b) {
    std::pair<T &, T &>(a, b) = std::make_pair(b, a);
}
```

Or, as a one-liner:

```
std::make_pair(std::ref(a), std::ref(b)) = std::make_pair(b, a);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you change a little the question to ask about 2 assembly registers instead of variables, you can use also the `xchg` operation as one option, and the stack operation as another one.

Comment: What `xchg` operation are you referring to? The question didn't specify a CPU architecture.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one more solution but a single risk.

code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
void main()
{

int a =10 , b =45;
*(&a+1 ) = a;
a =b;
b =*(&a +1);
}
```

any value at location a+1 will be overridden.

Comment: It was a useful answer, perhaps the value vanished.

Comment: Several kinds of undefined behavior. `*(&a+1)` might well be `b`. `void main()` is invalid. `<conio.h>` is non-standard (and you don't even use it).

Comment: The code was tested with other output parameters, which excluded, as I have mentioned a risk. The risk of memory overridden.. That's there.. But it was a useful swapping two variables without involvement of third.

Comment: The worst part is that it may actually work some times, so you might not immediately realize it is completely broken and will fail under optimization, other compilers, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Since the original solution is:

```
temp = x; y = x; x = temp;
```

You can make it a two liner by using:

```
temp = x; y = y + temp -(x=y);
```

Then make it a one liner by using:

```
x = x + y -(y=x);
```

Comment: Undefined behavior. `y` is read and written in the same expression with no intervening sequence point.

Answer (score 1):

Consider `a=10`, `b=15`:

> Using Addition and Subtraction

```
a = a + b //a=25
b = a - b //b=10
a = a - b //a=15
```

> Using Division and multiplication

```
a = a * b //a=150
b = a / b //b=10
a = a / b //a=15
```

Comment: Has undefined behavior on overflow.

Comment: Also, in C++, it may have undesirable behavior when the values are not the same type. For example, `a=10` and `b=1.5`.

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main(void)
{   
 int a,b;
 cout<<"Enter a integer" <<endl;
 cin>>a;
 cout<<"\n Enter b integer"<<endl;
 cin>>b;

  a = a^b;
  b = a^b;
  a = a^b;

  cout<<" a= "<<a <<"   b="<<b<<endl;
  return 0;
}
```

**Update:** In this we are taking input of two integers from user. Then we are using the bitwise *XOR* operation to swap them.

Say we have two integers `a=4` and `b=9` and then:

```
a=a^b --> 13=4^9 
b=a^b --> 4=13^9 
a=a^b --> 9=13^9
```

Comment: Please add short explanation to your answer for future visitors.

Comment: In this we are taking input of two integers from user. 
Then we are using the bitwise xor operation two swap them. 
Say we have two intergers a=4 and b=9 then 
now a=a^b  --> 13=4^9
   b=a^b -->   4=13^9
   a=a^b -->   9=13^9

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int a, b;
    printf("Enter A :");
    scanf("%d",&a);
    printf("Enter B :");
    scanf("%d",&b);
    a ^= b;
    b ^= a;
    a ^= b;
    printf("\nValue of A=%d B=%d ",a,b);
    return 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

that's the correct XOR swap algorithm

```
void xorSwap (int* x, int* y) {
   if (x != y) { //ensure that memory locations are different
      if (*x != *y) { //ensure that values are different
         *x ^= *y;
         *y ^= *x;
         *x ^= *y;
      }
   }
}
```

you have to ensure that memory locations are different and also that the actual values are different because A XOR A = 0

Comment: You don't have to ensure the values are different.

Answer (score 0):

You may do....in easy way...within one line Logic

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int a, b;
    printf("Enter A :");
    scanf("%d",&a);
    printf("Enter B :");
    scanf("%d",&b);
    int a = 1,b = 2;
    a=a^b^(b=a);
    printf("\nValue of A=%d B=%d ",a,b);

    return 1;
}
```

or

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int a, b;
    printf("Enter A :");
    scanf("%d",&a);
    printf("Enter B :");
    scanf("%d",&b);
    int a = 1,b = 2;
    a=a+b-(b=a);
    printf("\nValue of A=%d B=%d ",a,b);

    return 1;
}
```

Comment: Undefined behavior. In both versions, `b` is both read and modified within the same expression, with no intervening sequence point.

Answer (score 0):

```
public void swapnumber(int a,int b){
    a = a+b-(b=a);
    System.out.println("a = "+a +" b= "+b);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The best answer would be to use XOR and to use it in one line would be cool.

```
    (x ^= y), (y ^= x), (x ^= y);
```

x,y are variables and the comma between them introduces the sequence points so it does not become compiler dependent. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe off topic, but if you know what you are swapping a single variable between two different values, you may be able to do array logic. Each time this line of code is run, it will swap the value between 1 and 2.

```
n = [2, 1][n - 1]
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do:

```
std::tie(x, y) = std::make_pair(y, x);
```

Or use make_tuple when swapping more than two variables:

```
std::tie(x, y, z) = std::make_tuple(y, z, x);
```

But I'm not sure if internally std::tie uses a temporary variable or not!

Answer (score 0):

In javascript:

```
function swapInPlace(obj) {
    obj.x ^= obj.y
    obj.y ^= obj.x
    obj.x ^= obj.y
}

function swap(obj) {
    let temp = obj.x
    obj.x = obj.y
    obj.y = temp
}
```

Be aware to execution time of both options.

By run this code i measured it.

```
console.time('swapInPlace')
swapInPlace({x:1, y:2})
console.timeEnd('swapInPlace') // swapInPlace: 0.056884765625ms

console.time('swap')
swap({x:3, y:6})
console.timeEnd('swap')        // swap: 0.01416015625ms
```

As you can see (and as many said), swap in place (xor) take alot time than the other option using temp variable.

Answer (score 0):

R is missing a concurrent assignment as proposed by Edsger W. Dijkstra in *A Discipline of Programming*, 1976, ch.4, p.29. This would allow for an elegant solution:

```
a, b    <- b, a         # swap
a, b, c <- c, a, b      # rotate right
```

Answer (score 0):

How about,If we do with parallel processing with "GO" lang..

var x = 100;
var y = 200;

swap1 := func(var i) { x = i }
swap2 := func(var y) { y = i }
Parallelize(swap1, swap2)

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE :: a demo of what the effects are for the 3 types of swapping methods available in `awk`

— (`awk` doesn't offer true bit-wise `XOR`) :

- either `substr() wrapper` or `function and/or array` are truly lossless for any input, even when swapping ***arbitrary binary data*** in `gawk unicode-mode`,

  or when swapping completely different data types, like a
  unicode string with an approximation of euler's `e` that's beyond
  `IEEE 754` double-prec floating point precision
- `arithmetic-based swaps` are only lossless when both inputs are actually numeric, **not** potentially subject to special interpretation rules, e.g. built-in hex decoding in some `awk` variants when you place a unary `+` or `-` in front of it, ***AND*** both inputs are entirely within the current precision level. ***`USE IT WITH CAUTION`***

> 

```
  echo '91223951291111 '\
       '8777175273333\n' \
                          \
       'abc@\uF8FF_123^456#\0306\02222\\|/<>[]{\0354\0210\0657}()&+- '\

       '2.7182818284590452353602874713526624977
          5724709369995957496696762772407663035
          35475945713821785251\n' \
                                    \ 
       'FTX_ThreeArrows_Luna_Terra ' \
       'abc345\0301\0375fgc'         | 

    LANG='en_US.UTF-8' LC_ALL= gawk -e '

    BEGIN {
     1      __________ = "\f\r\t\t..."
    }  {
     3      split(_=__=___ = "",____)
    }
       {
     3      print ">ORIGINAL_INPUT :: ", _ = $++__, 
                            __________, __ = $++__, 
                   "\n--------------- :: --------------"\
                                          "--------------\n"

     3      _ = __ substr("", (__=_)^(_<_))
     3      print "substr(..)-swap :: ", _, __________, __

     3      ____[++___] = _
     3      ____[++___] = __
     3               swap(____)
     3               __ = ____[___--]
     3                _ = ____[___--]
     3      print "func+array-swap :: ",_,__________,__

     3      _ -= __ = (_+=__) - __
     3      print "arithmetic-swap :: ",_,__________,__
     3      print "__________"
    }
    function swap(__,_,___) {
            ___ = __[++_]
          __[_] = __[_+_]
                  __[_+_] = ___
    }'
```

> 

```
>ORIGINAL_INPUT ::  91223951291111 
                ... 8777175273333 
--------------- :: -------------- --------------

substr(..)-swap ::  8777175273333 
                ... 91223951291111

func+array-swap ::  91223951291111 
                ... 8777175273333

arithmetic-swap ::  8777175273333 
                ... 91223951291111
__________
>ORIGINAL_INPUT ::  abc@_123^456#ƒ2\|/<>[]{숯}()&+- 
        ... 2.7182818284590452353602874713526624977572470936999595749669676277240766303535475945713821785251 
--------------- :: -------------- --------------

substr(..)-swap ::  2.7182818284590452353602874713526624977572470936999595749669676277240766303535475945713821785251 
                ... abc@_123^456#ƒ2\|/<>[]{숯}()&+-

func+array-swap ::  abc@_123^456#ƒ2\|/<>[]{숯}()&+- 
        ...  2.7182818284590452353602874713526624977572470936999595749669676277240766303535475945713821785251


arithmetic-swap ::  2.71828 
        ... 0
__________

>ORIGINAL_INPUT ::  FTX_ThreeArrows_Luna_Terra 
                ... abc345??fgc 
--------------- :: -------------- --------------

substr(..)-swap ::  abc345??fgc 
                ... FTX_ThreeArrows_Luna_Terra

func+array-swap ::  FTX_ThreeArrows_Luna_Terra 
                ... abc345??fgc

arithmetic-swap ::  0 
        ... 0
__________
```

---

In `awk`, without needing a temp variable, a temp array, an external function call, substring-ing their values out of one another, XOR operations, or even any math operations of any sort,

this trick works for whether their values are numeric, string, or even arbitrary bytes that aren't UTF8-compliant, nor do the types of the 2 variables even need to match :

```
      gawk/mawk/nawk '{ 
                       a = (b) \
          substr("", ( b = (a) )^"")
      }'
```

Even in Unicode-locale, `gawk` unicode mode could swap the values of `arbitrary non-UTF8 bytes` without any error messages.

No need to use C or POSIX locale.

Why it works is that in the process of this concatenation, the original value of `b` has already been placed in some system-internal staging ground, so the sub-sequent `assignment of b's value into a` does not have any impact into what's being assigned into `a`

The second half of it is taking a substring of an empty string, so of course nothing comes out, and doesn't affect the first half.

After `b = a`, I immediately take the zero-th power of it, which always returns a 1 in awk

so the latter portion becomes

```
  # in awk, string indices start from 1 not 0
  
  substr(EMPTY_STRING, STARTING-POSITION-OF-ONE)
```

of course nothing comes out of it, which is the desired effect, so the clean original value of `b` could be assigned into `a`.

This isn't taking a substring of `a`'s or `b`'s value. It's taking advantage of dynamic typing properties of awk.

A XOR-based approach, which clean, still require 3 operations, plus a safety check against being memory position (for C). And for gnu-awk, its `xor()` function only works with non-negative numeric inputs.

This one-liner approach circumvents all the common issues with value swapping.

Either `a` or `b`, or even both, being an array cell, regardless of single or multi-dimensional, e.g.

```
arr[ _pos_idx_a_ ]
```

works exactly the same with this one-liner approach. The only limitation I could think of is that this approach cannot directly swap full contents of an entire array with another array.

I thought of adding a check for a==b to avoid a double assignment, but then realized the internal system resources needed to perform such a check is not worth the minuscule amount of time saved.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code: (sample in php)

```
$a = 5;
$b = 7;
 echo $a .' ***Before*** '. $b;
$a = $a + $b; //12
$b = $a - $b; //12 - 7 = 5
$a = $a - $b; //12 - 5 = 7
 echo $a .' ***After*** '. $b;
```

Comment: The OP has asked the question for `C++` language. Please [edit] to change the language to `C++`

Answer (score 0):

I think **std::exchange** can be used from C++14

```
int a = 8;
int b = 10;

std::cout << a << "  " << b << std::endl;

//Returns b and Replaces b with a.
a = std::exchange(b, a); 

std::cout << a << "  " << b << std::endl;
```

Answer (score -1):

```
a = a + b - (b=a);
```

It's very simple, but it may raise a warning.

Comment: The warning  being that it doesn't work? We don't know if `b=a` is performed before or after `a + b`.

Answer (score -1):

single line solution for swapping two values in c language.

```
a=(b=(a=a+b,a-b),a-b);
```

Comment: Undefined behavior on overflow.

Answer (score -1):

```
second_value -= first_value;
first_value +=  second_value;
second_value -= first_value;
second_value *= -1;
```

Comment: This has undefined behavior if any of the operations overflow or underflow. It can also lose precision if the objects are floating-point.