# Interchanging values of two variables by xor operator using references or pointers

Tags: c++, reference, swap, xor

I have two integer variables i and j and I want to make a function which takes these two variables as its argument and interchanges their contents using xor operator. Now if I make the function to take arguments by value i.e `void swap (int x , int y);`(with function body same as for the function `swap` below) then the values are being swapped nicely within the function. But as what I want is the swapping of the values of the variables in the calling function I used passing arguments by reference (and by pointers as well) :

```
void swap ( int& x , int& y )
{
    x^=y^=x^=y;
    cout << x<< " " << y << endl ;
}

int main ()
{
    int i (1), j (2) ;
    swap ( i, j ) ;
    cout << i << " " << j << endl ;
}
```

but neither case showed the correct result !

Why is the `swap` function not swapping the values on passing arguments by reference or pointers ?

Comment: :You realise that c++ has std:: swap? So you don't have to do inadvisable things like xor swap.

Comment: Xor swapping is inadvisable in any case unless you are implementing a system-specific library function and have proved that it is faster on your system. And you have not addressed the horrible failure mode when `x` aliases `y`.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth_ were you referring to vector::swap ?

Comment: @cirronimbo: No. `std::swap` in <algorithm> (in C++03) or <utility> (in C++11).

Comment: @dmckee_ I thought it was the most efficient method of swapping as here even we dont need to take an extra variable as well ! Then why it is so unadvisable ?

Comment: @cirronimbo : [`std::swap`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/swap).

Comment: @cirronimbo, Compilers can make more optimizations with `std::swap`. It ends up being better, and more straightforward.

Comment: (1) You are only guessing that it is faster (2) as you have written it is may confuse some older compilers and it has the aliasing bug and (3) it is less clear than just writing `temp = y; y = x; x = temp`. Write what you *mean* and let the compiler optimize unless and until you have *proved* that this is not good enough.

Comment: [Reasons for avoiding XOR swap in practice](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XOR_swap_algorithm#Reasons_for_avoidance_in_practice)

Comment: @Blastfurnace_ Thanks. That was eye-opening !

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to swap two numbers without using temp variables or arithmetic operations?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3647331/how-to-swap-two-numbers-without-using-temp-variables-or-arithmetic-operations)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> I have two integer variables i and j and I want to make a function
>   which takes these two variables as its argument and interchanges their
>   contents using xor operator.

Why?

As you've figured out, you need either to pass pointers to the objects, or to use references.

This:

```
x^=y^=x^=y;
```

has undefined behavior, since it modifies the same object twice between sequence points (it does this for both `x` and `y`).

The xor trick fails if both objects are the same object; the first xor zeros the object.

If you want to swap two objects, just use a temporary:

```
int temp = x;
x = y;
y = temp;
```

It's simple, and it *works*.

Comment: that means even if I make the function take _arguments by value_ then too I might get the wrong result in some other compiler ?

Comment: Yes, although the by value or by reference of the things doesn't have any bearing on the fact that `x^=y^=x^=y` is undefined.

Comment: One of the reasons I like Python, easy swap :-)  `x, y = y, x`

Comment: @Levon - `std::swap(x, y)` isn't too bad either. But some people just want to make it the hard way.

Answer (score 2):

As others have noted, this is a pretty silly optimization (if you can call it that).  The problem is the chained use of in-place operators.  Broken it into separable statements, it works.

```
x^=y;  // values are X^Y, Y
y^=x;  // values are X^Y, X
x^=y;  // values are Y, X
```

Like the others, I would encourage you not to riddle your code with such clarity-killing cleverness unless you have a demonstrable need established by profiling and a demonstrable speedup for doing your [bit twiddling hack](http://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html#SwappingValuesXOR). (cool site)

Comment: Thanks. I should've figure this out. I always tend to forget the sequence points..