# How to reverse String in place in Java

Tags: java, string

How to reverse String in place in Java

input String  : 1234
Output Should : 4321

what i have tried.

```
public static void main(String args[]) 
{ 
 String number = "1234"; 
 System.out.println("original String: " + number); String reversed = inPlaceReverse(number);
 System.out.println("reversed String: " + reversed);
}



public static String inPlaceReverse(final String input) 
{
   final StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder(input); 
   int length = builder.length();
   for (int i = 0; i < length / 2; i++)
   {
      final char current = builder.charAt(i); 
      final int otherEnd = length - i - 1;
      builder.setCharAt(i, builder.charAt(otherEnd)); // swap 
      builder.setCharAt(otherEnd, current); 
   }
 return builder.toString(); 
}
```

i am getting answer like:
reversed String: 4231 as i expected 4321.

Comment: https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: Your code works. I get "4321" from `inPlaceReverse("1234")`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reverse a string in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7569335/reverse-a-string-in-java)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If your teacher wants to see your work then you should manipulate the chars directly. Something like the following should be enough to let you spot the mistake:

```
public static String reverse(String orig)
{
    char[] s = orig.toCharArray();
    final int n = s.length;
    final int halfLength = n / 2;
    for (int i=0; i<halfLength; i++)
    {
        char temp = s[i];
        s[i] = s[n-1-i];
        s[n-1-i] = temp;
    }
    return new String(s);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It can be even simpler using [StringBuilder's **`reverse()`**](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/lang/stringbuilder_reverse.htm) function:

```
public static String inPlaceReverse(String input) {
   StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder(input); 
   return builder.reverse().toString();
}
```

Comment: hehe, he won't get marks for using such API. I think the teacher wanted "showing your work" :)

Comment: @MinhKieu Yeah, maybe. Let's say this is the *without reinventing the wheel* answer, for further readers ;P

Comment: @Mistalis - I wonder why the StringBuilder class provides such a function but String does not. Either there is a good reason, or the developers of StringBuilder did too many coding interview questions :P

Answer (score 0):

```
public static String inPlaceReverse(String number) {
        char[] ch = number.toCharArray();
        int i = 0;
        int j = number.length()-1;
        while (i < j) {
            char temp = ch[i];
            ch[i] = ch[j];
            ch[j] = temp;
            i++;
            j--;
        }
        return String.valueOf(ch);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

**1. Using Character Array:**

```
public String reverseSting(String inputString) {
    char[] inputStringArray = inputString.toCharArray();
    String reverseString = "";
    for (int i = inputStringArray.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        reverseString += inputStringArray[i];
    }
    return reverseString;
}
```

**2. Using StringBuilder:**

```
public String reverseSting(String inputString) {
    StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder(inputString);
    stringBuilder = stringBuilder.reverse();
    return stringBuilder.toString();
}
```

**OR**

```
return new StringBuilder(inputString).reverse().toString();
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an interview question.
Reverse a String in place :

```
public class Solution4 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String a = "Protijayi";

        System.out.println(reverse(a)); //iyajitorP
    }

    private static String reverse(String a) {
           char[] ca = a.toCharArray();
           int start = 0 ; int end = a.length()-1;
           while(end > start) {
               swap(ca,start,end);
               start++;
               end--;
           }//while

        return new String(ca);
    }

    private static void swap(char[] ca, int start, int end) {
        char t = ca[start];
        ca[start] = ca[end];
        ca[end] = t ;
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Mind also, that you can avoid using additional memory during the swap, though having some extra computation.

```
public class StringReverser {

public static String reverseStringInPlace(String toReverse) {

    char[] chars = toReverse.toCharArray();

    int inputStringLength = toReverse.length();

    for (int i = 0; i < inputStringLength / 2; i++) {
        int toMoveBack = toReverse.charAt(i);
        int toMoveForward = toReverse.charAt(inputStringLength - i - 1);

        //swap
        toMoveForward = toMoveBack - toMoveForward;
        toMoveBack -= toMoveForward;
        toMoveForward += toMoveBack;

        chars[i] = (char) toMoveBack;
        chars[inputStringLength - i - 1] = (char) toMoveForward;
    }

    return String.valueOf(chars);

}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    System.out.println(reverseStringInPlace("asd0")); // output: 0dsa
    System.out.println(reverseStringInPlace("sd0")); // output: 0ds
    System.out.println(reverseStringInPlace("")); // output: empty
    System.out.println(reverseStringInPlace("-")); // output: -
    System.out.println(reverseStringInPlace("ABD+C")); // output: C+DBA
    System.out.println(reverseStringInPlace("勒")); // output: 勒
    System.out.println(reverseStringInPlace("分歧。")); // output: 。歧分
    System.out.println(reverseStringInPlace("Marítimo")); // output: omitíraM
} 
}
```

Relevant to swap discussion can be found here:
[How to swap two numbers without using temp variables or arithmetic operations?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3647331/how-to-swap-two-numbers-without-using-temp-variables-or-arithmetic-operations)

Answer (score 0):

Convert the string to a character array first and then use recursion.

```
public void reverseString(char[] s) {
    helper(0, s.length - 1, s);
}

private void helper(int left, int right, char[] s){
    if(left >= right) {
        return;
    }

    char temp = s[left];
    s[left++] = s[right];
    s[right--] = temp;
    helper(left, right, s);
}
```

So with the input `[1,2,3,4]`, the helper function will be called as follows :

```
1. helper(0, 3, [1,2,3,4]), Swap 1 and 4
2. helper(1, 2, [1,2,3,4]), Swap 2 and 3
3. helper(2, 1, [1,2,3,4]) Terminates, left is now greater than right
```

Answer (score 0):

After converting into char array. Just swap the both ends ( first index, last index) and move towards each other(first index to last index and from last index to first) until the crossing.

```
 public void reverseString(char[] s) {
        
        int start = 0;
        int end = s.length-1;
        char temp = ' ';
        while((start)<(end)){
            temp = s[start];
            s[start] = s[end];
            s[end] = temp;
            start++;
            end--;
        }
        
        System.out.println(s);
        
    }
```