# Swapping using two variables not three?

Tags: programming-languages

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Swapping two variable value without using 3rd variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1826159/swapping-two-variable-value-without-using-3rd-variable)

we have

```
int a=4;
int b=7;
```

can i swap these no.s without using third variable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
a=a+b;
b=a-b;
a=a-b;
```

Comment: Sure it is -- see gspr's answer.

Comment: @Hogan realised that very quickly and changed answer, sorry for confusion.

Comment: @yang , how can you say?

Comment: @Guri Jeff is correct, this is susceptible to overflow. The XOR method would be better.

Comment: @fredley: Only in programming languages with broken arithmetic. There *are* actually programming languages which *can* add two numbers correctly.

Comment: @fredley: I find it kind of sad that the fact that 2 billion plus 2 billion equals 4 billion is *still* considered an exciting and exotic feature in 2010.

Answer (score 2):

The precise implementation of course depends on the programming language you're using, but check out [XOR swap](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XOR_swap_algorithm).

An example in C could be

```
#include <stdio.h>

/* Swaps the content pointed to by a and b. The memory pointed to is
   assumed non-overlapping! */

void swap(int* a, int* b)
{
  *a = (*a)^(*b);
  *b = (*a)^(*b);
  *a = (*a)^(*b);
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
  int a = 4;
  int b = 7;
  printf("a=%d, b=%d\n", a, b);
  swap(&a, &b);
  printf("a=%d, b=%d\n", a, b);
  return 0;
}
```

**Important:** As Prasoon Saurav commented on the question itself, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1826159/swapping-two-variable-value-without-using-3rd-variable/1826175#1826175) to another question is more correct than mine, seeing as it is important that the two variables reside at non-overlapping locations in memory. My example does not check for this.

Answer (score 1):

a=a+b;  //a=11,b=7

b=a-b;  //a=11,b4

a=a-b;  //a=7,b=4

or

a=a*b;

b=a/b;

a=b/a;

but careful with this method, overflow or underflow is possible for some combinations.

Comment: All liable to overflow/underflow with certain number combinations.

Answer (score 0):

Sure: `a,b = b,a` works in various programming languages.

In others you can use the [xor trick](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XOR_swap_algorithm).