# How can we swap two numbers without third variable and without arithmetic operator?

Tags: java

How can we swap two numbers without third variable and without arithmetic operator?

Comment: One possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/756750/swap-the-values-of-two-variables-without-using-third-variable

Comment: Why would you want to do that?

Comment: Another possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1826159/swapping-two-variable-value-without-using-3rd-variable

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Does XOR count as an arithmetic Operator? If not, then:

```
X := X XOR Y
Y := X XOR Y
X := X XOR Y
```

Converting this pseudo-code to Java code that compiles is left as an exercise to the reader (with regards to the ‘java’ tag).

Comment: If I remember correctly, though, this won't work if one of the values you're trying to swap is 0.

Comment: And no, a value of zero is no problem at all.

Comment: Funny, I always thought that XOR was arithmetic, but at least it isn't the +, -, *, or / operators the poster is probably thinking about.

Comment: @Edwin, @Florian: XOR is a bitwise operator, so this fits the given requirements. @Shynthriir: 0 is fine, but it *is* a problem if X and Y refer to the same location in memory.

Answer (score 2):

```
private static void swap() {
    int a = 5;
    int b = 6;
    System.out.println("Before Swaping: a = " + a + " and b= " + b);
    // swapping value of two numbers without using temp variable and XOR bitwise operator
    a = a ^ b; // now a is 3 and b is 6
    b = a ^ b; // now a is 3 but b is 5 (original value of a)
    a = a ^ b; // now a is 6 and b is 5, numbers are swapped
    System.out.println("After  Swaping: a = " + a + " and b= " + b);

}
```

Output :

```
Before Swaping: a = 5 and b= 6
After  Swaping: a = 6 and b= 5
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public class SwapNumbers {

 public static void main(String[] args) {

  int x = 11;
  int y = 22;

  System.out.println("Before Swapping");
  System.out.println("Value of x is :" + x);
  System.out.println("Value of y is :" + y);

  x = x + y;
  y = x - y;
  x = x - y;

  System.out.println("Before Swapping");
  System.out.println("Value of x is :" + x);
  System.out.println("Value of y is :" + y);
 }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
class Swap{

 int a;
 int b; 

 public static void main(String args[]){
    a = 10;
    b =20;
    System.out.println("******Before Swap*********");
    System.out.println("a= "+a);
    System.out.println("b= "+b);
    a = a + b;
    b = a - b;
    a = a - b;
    System.out.println("******After Swap*********");
    System.out.println("a= "+a);
    System.out.println("b= "+b);
 } 
}
```

**Your Output will be :**

******Before Swap*********
a= 10
b= 20
******After Swap*********
a= 20
b= 10

Answer (score -4):

Using this ::

```
X = X ^ Y;
Y = X ^ Y;
X = X ^ Y;
*** ^ means XOR operation
```

Comment: But + and - are arithmetic operators which is exactly what you're not allowed to use.

Comment: Ok. check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/756750/swap-the-values-of-two-variables-without-using-third-variable.

Comment: Rolled back the inappropriate edit which just changed this answer into the other one.