# How do I store a value for later use?

Tags: c++, variables

if I have 2 variables to set equal to each other how would I go about that? for example, if I had 2 numbers (3 , 8) so xval = 3 and yval = 8 how would I swap them with the following procedure?

```
xval = yval;
yval = xval;
```

this would just set both values to y which would output (8 , 8). I remember earlier in my lass there was a function to store a value for later use but I forgot what it was

Comment: Declare a third temporary variable, or better use `std::swap`.

Comment: And a more exotic one if you are dealing with integers, you can use XOR operations, no third variable needed. E.g., swap value of `a` with `b`: `a^= b; b^=a; a^=b`. The fundamental behind that is that `x^x==0`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3933432/9248466

Comment: @zois  The XOR swap, on modern architectures, is usually slower than a swap that involves a temporary variable and also (if it is to work) inhibits some optimisations related to instruction pipelining (if those optimisations are not inhibited, the swap isn't guaranteed to actually work).   It also doesn't work if `a` and `b` overlap in memory (e.g. one is an alias of the other, directly or indirectly).

Answer (score -1):

#### 1. Using pre-defined swap

```
std::swap(xval , yval);
```

#### 2. Using temporary variable

```
int temp=xval;
xval = yval;
yval = temp;
```

#### 3. Without using the temporary variable  (Watch for overflow)

```
xval = xval+yval;
yval = xval-yval;
xval = xval-yval;
```

#### 4. Using XOR

```
xval = xval ^ yval ^ (yval = xval);
```

Comment: Watch out for overflow with the second option

Comment: You forgot the idiomatic and probably best solution: [`std::swap`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/swap).

Comment: @churill yes, i have updated answer now

Comment: Update: Watch for overflow in the third option.