# Swapping the values of two variables without using third variable in C?

Tags: c, expression, operator-precedence, sequence-points

I've found the following code snippet:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    int x=10,y=15;
    x=x+y-(y=x);
    printf("x=%d y=%d",x,y);
    return 0;
}
```

> It actually swaps the variables

Can anybody explain me how the the code swaps the variable?

I thought the bracket would execute first and then expression leads to

```
x=x+y-y;
```

Comment: I believe it's swapping them merely by chance - this looks like *undefined behavior* (specifically relating to sequence points)

Comment: This is definitely undefined behaviour.

Comment: Compiling with gcc -Wall gives: `so.c:5:13: warning: operation on ‘y’ may be undefined [-Wsequence-point]`

Comment: @Tryin, Where did you find this snippet?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why are these constructs undefined behavior?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/949433/why-are-these-constructs-undefined-behavior)

Comment: @Deduplicator I thought about it, but it seems a bit like shoe horning to me.

Comment: It has such expressions and explains their behavior. The OPs question imho fits because it is "explain me the code".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This algorithm does not work because it invokes undefined behavior on this line:

```
x=x+y-(y=x);
    ^  ^
```

You are modifying `y` and also using its value within the same sequence point as per section `6.5` of the draft C99 standard:

> Between the previous and next sequence point an object shall have its
>   stored value modified at most once by the evaluation of an
>   expression.72) Furthermore, the prior value shall be read only to
>   determine the value to be stored.73)

There is also the matter of unspecified behavior since the order of evaluation of the sub-expressions is unspecified:

> The grouping of operators and operands is indicated by the syntax.74)
>   Except as specified later (for the function-call (), &&, ||, ?:, and
>   comma operators), the order of evaluation of subexpressions and the
>   order in which side effects take place are both unspecified.

In this case if you were using `clang` it would have provided the following warning:

```
warning: unsequenced modification and access to 'y' [-Wunsequenced]
x=x+y-(y=x);
    ~   ^
```

as far as I can tell by default. You can receive a similar warning from `gcc` by using `-Wall`.

There are several SO questions that cover how to swap without a temporary for example [Swapping two variable value without using 3rd variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1826159/swapping-two-variable-value-without-using-3rd-variable?lq=1).

Comment: An extra point worth mentioning is that there are two other ways of doing this: either a dedicated platform-specific instruction, or the "xor swap trick". The former is not portable/standard, and the latter is not safe.

Comment: The xor swap trick is safe if you manually introduce sequence points, i.e. `x^=y;y^=x;x^=y;`, but you're probably better off just using a third variable anyway. (this of course assumes the variables are integer types).

Answer (score 2):

This is actually a result of *undefined behavior*, due to something called *sequence points*. Basically, in this case, the C standard does not require the values to be stored in any order during evaluation of the expression. In fact, the following is certainly possible:

1. Evaluate `y = x`, and store the value in `y`. In this case, `x` is still 10, and `y` is now also 10. The expression itself evaluates to 10 (the left-hand side of the assignment).
2. Evaluate `x = x + y - (y = x)`, which equates to `x = x + y - 10`. `x` and `y` are both 10, so this is `x = 10 + 10 - 10`, so `x` is now 10.

Now, `x` and `y` are both 10, and the original value 15 is now lost.

Edit: as far as how it *can* swap, it could be due to the optimization:

1. Evaluate `y = x`, but don't store the value in `y` yet. `y` then still holds the value 15, whilst the assignment expression evaluates to 10.
2. Now, `x = x + y - 10` evaluates to `x = 10 + 15 - 10`, yielding the correct value.

Both scenarios are valid, but produce different results.

Comment: It doesn't have to be an optimization; it just performs the `x + y` bit first. I.e., `x = 10 + 15 - (y = 10);`. So it's undefined behavior, yes, but it's not due to any optimization that it happens to work on some compilers.

Comment: But such an optimization *can* happen; that's the whole point of UB.

Comment: Yes, it can; just wanted to point out another alternative that you had left out.

Comment: There's probably many more alternatives, I just wanted to point out two that had different results

Answer (score 2):

> I thought the bracket would execute first ...

That's an invalid assumption. Parentheses effect the precedence of operators in an expression. They do not specify order of execution. In

```
 a = b + c + (d * e);
```

it may well be that `b + c` is computed before `(d * e)`. Or it may not. The C language standard leaves the order of evaluation of the sub expression **unspecified**. The code you posted invokes **undefined behavior** due to `y` being read and written to without an intervening sequence point. Note again that parentheses do not introduce sequence points (the semicolon does).

Comment: @FiddlingBits, They are the same for many people, including me. I tend to use square brackets and parentheses respectively, though.

Comment: @AndrewMedico, I feel out of place as a Canadian now, but that happens with every American vs. British debate, so meh.