# Strange swap macro

Tags: c++

I typed these code. However, the output is beyond my expectations.

```
#define SWAP(x,y) {x=x^y;y=x^y;x=x^y;}
#define SWAP2(x,y) {x=x+y;y=x-y;x=x-y;}
int main()
{
    int ia[] = { 1, 10, 1 };
    SWAP(ia[0], ia[0]);   // the resutl is ia[0] = 0
    SWAP(ia[1], ia[2]);   // work fine
    SWAP2(ia[1], ia[1])   // the result is ia[0] = 0    
}
```

Anyone can help me? Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Why are you swapping an array item with itself?

Comment: Why would use use a macro for this?

Comment: Why write confusing code? Macros are hard to debug. Best to avoid. Anyway C++ has `std::swap`

Comment: @VioletGiraffe Presumably to test the swap implementation, or in a context that doesn't know they're the same.

Comment: @shuttle87 The xor trick is a classic in-place swap algorithm that doesn't require a third memory space. It's confusing to read, though, so it should be hidden somehow, and a function would need to be inlined (which is never guaranteed) in order to preserve that feature.

Comment: @EdHeal C++11/14/1z do, yes, but not all projects have up-to-date compilers or enable modern settings.

Comment: @KyleStrand - If not available - quite easy to write.

Comment: Read the [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XOR_swap_algorithm). It explains why you can't use XOR to swap a variable with itself.

Comment: @EdHeal Well, obviously not, or OP presumably would have gotten it right!

Comment: @Graywd - You might also want to read [Swapping two variable values without using 3rd variable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1826159/swapping-two-variable-value-without-using-3rd-variable) to see that your code not only fails sometimes, but also runs a lot slower than code using a temp variable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is that your swap algorithms *require* the two arguments to be *separate* pieces of memory.

As noted by LYF_HKN, the first step in each algorithm causes `x` to become 0 when `x=y`. If the two are merely *equal* but are still *separate* pieces of memory, this is fine, because the second step will leave `y` unchanged (because `x` is 0), and the third step will restore the original value of `x` *if* `y` is now equal to that original value.

However, when `x` and `y` are actually the *same* object in memory, then the first operation in each algorithm, in setting `x` to 0, *also* sets `y` to 0, since `y` *is* `x`. Thus the rest of each algorithm merely preserves the value 0 in this memory space.

Answer (score 3):

The first SWAP:

```
ia[0] = ia[0] ^ ia[0];
ia[0] = ia[0] ^ ia[0];
ia[0] = ia[0] ^ ia[0];
```

Well, any value XOR'd with itself gives zero. That's why the first SWAP result in ia[0] becoming zero.
The second one is fine, so I will skip it and jump into the third one.

```
ia[1] = ia[1] + ia[1];
ia[1] = ia[1] - ia[1];
ia[1] = ia[1] - ia[1];
```

What is the result of ia[1] - ia[1]? Always zero regardless of the value of ia[1].

Comment: Yes, any value xor'd with itself is 0, but that's not where the algorithm ends. Same for the second algorithm. And algorithmically, there's no distinction here between using a macro and using a function.

Comment: Yes, my mistake, sorry. It still refers to the same variable and leads to the same result.

Answer (score 2):

The first `SWAP` is called `XOR swap`, it can swap two different variables without a temp variable. However, the two variables must have different addresses. That's the reason `SWAP(ia[0], ia[0]);` fails, but `SWAP(ia[1], ia[2]);` works fine.

The second `SWAP2` is dangerous, since `x+y` might overflow. And you should not use that one.

To make the `XOR swap` work, you need to some modification:

```
void swap(int &x, int &y) {
    if (&x != &y) {
        x ^= y;
        y ^= x;
        x ^= y;
    }
}
```

Comment: Call your `swap` like this: `int a = 42, b = 42; swap(a, b);` and observe.

Comment: If you are going to write a function, why not just do it properly without the rigmarole of XOR?

Comment: @EdHeal Whether it's a function or macro is not OP's question. Whether `std::swap` is better than XOR swap is not OP's question either. I'm just trying to explain why he didn't get what's he expected, and how to fix it.