# Swap two numbers without a third in C/C++

Tags: c++

we usually use the

```
a=a+b; 
b=a-b; 
a=a-b;
```

logic to solve this code, however, if we work with `int`, then after say `30000` the code fails, if we take `long`, it fails after say `1000000` or so. My objective is, not to increase the length of the code yet, do the same operation. I have already tried using a `BIT wise XOR`,

```
a = a ^ b;
b = a ^ b;
a = a ^ b;
```

Still it didn't help, any ideas?

Comment: Welcome to SO :-) Can you explain what you mean by "the code fails"? What exactly goes wrong?

Comment: Looks like http://stackoverflow.com/q/1826159/2579220

Comment: If  `a` and `b` are too large, addition may go out of `integer` range.

Comment: The irony is that all attempts to avoid using an extra variable results in larger code that runs slower. And has extra bugs in it.

Comment: This sounds like an [X-Y](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) problem. *Why* do you want to do this?

Comment: "we usually use" - typo, should be "we never use".

Comment: Stefan Hegny, code fails means that garbage values are taken

Answer (score 5):

To swap a variable `a` and a variable `b`: `std::swap(a, b);`
Example:

```
int a = 10;
int b = 20;

std::cout << "Before swap\n";
std::cout << "Value of a: " << a << '\n';
std::cout << "Value of b: " << b << '\n';

std::swap(a, b);

std::cout << "After swap\n";
std::cout << "Value of a: " << a << '\n';
std::cout << "Value of b: " << b << '\n';
```

Output using GCC 4.9.2:

> Before swap
>   Value of a: 10
>   Value of b: 20
>   After swap
>   Value of a: 20
>   Value of b: 10

This way of doing it uses rvalues internally, so it has next to zero overhead for other use cases and won't overflow for any primitive type ever

Comment: Moving an int has exactly the same cost as copying it. And no, std::swap specifically doesn't work with r-values (it uses them internally, but again, for int that doesn't make a difference).

Comment: @MikeMB good point about using rvalues only internally, I thought it would be clear in the context. Edited to bo explicit. And yes, it's the same for ints, but I try to answer questions as broadly applicable as possible, so I wanted to point out the general benefits of `std::swap`

Comment: Its also the question, if the answer to: "I don't want to use a third variable"  is to create 1 (effectively 3) new variables in a function and call that function.

Comment: @PatrickM'Bongo I'm sorry if my choice of words is confusing. What I'm trying to convey is that there's a possible runtime cost associated with operations such as `a-b;`, which is not present using `b = std::move(a)` internally. Also yes, in this specific example the temp variable that is probably created (not guaranteed to, though) uses a regular copy. The real benefit starts kicking in as soon as the OP uses `std::swap` for non-primitive data types like `std::vector<int>` , which will not generate copying overhead.