# How do you add the same value to two variables in one statment?

Tags: javascript

It is possible to initialize multiple variables to the same value `a=b=5`. Also, it is possible to add to a variable with `a+=2`. But is there any way to add the same value to both at the same time? Something like this `a+=b+=2` without the `a` getting incremented by the value of `2` and `b`. So in this case both `a` and `b` would end up being 7.

Also, I'm not looking for an answer that repeats the added value such as `a+=2,b+=2`.

I realize this is not the greatest coding practice I just wondered if it was possible. Somewhat similar in nature to [Swapping two variable value without using 3rd variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1826159/swapping-two-variable-value-without-using-3rd-variable)

Comment: why do you need to do this?

Comment: Prefer readability over conciseness. Write code that won't make you scratch your head in a month.

Comment: if you want to initialize two variables to the same value: `var a = 2, b = a;` or `var a,b; a=b=2;` to add the same value to two variables, use a third variable: `var amount = 2; a += amount, b += amount`; That's what vars are for, to store values.

Comment: `a = b = 5;` does as expected (not `var a=b=5` though) ... adding the same value - not so easy

Comment: I don't necessarily need it. It probably would make the code less maintainable, but I was curious to see if it was possible. My scenario is I have two properties that I need to increment by the same amount, but that amount is a derived from a ternary statement.

Comment: Not sure what expected result is? _"My scenario is I have two properties that I need to increment by the same amount, but that amount is a derived from a ternary statement."_ Can you include `javascript` that you have tried at Question?

Comment: I realised, that's why I removed the comment @Thomas :p

Comment: @guest271314 something like `var a=5,b=7; ` Then you want to add the result of `foo?2:3`. So if false the result would be 8 and 10.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You *can* do it! Here's how to:

```
var a = 10;
var b = 15;
b += -a + (a += 10);  // In this case, adding 10 to both
console.log(a, b);  //=> 20 25
```

**BOOM** (yes it blew my own mind too)

Sometimes it doesn't matter *why* you do it, it just matters that you *can* do it!

---

So, how / why does it work?

The `-a` gets parsed and becomes the negative value of `a`, which is 10 (so -10). Then, `a += 10` runs and sets `a` to 20 (10 + 10). Finally, it sums up both values (`-10 + 20`) and gives you the difference between old `a` and new `a`.

Gorgeous.

---

**EDIT:**
For completion's sake, as of ES6's [destructuring assignments](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment), you could do:

```
let a = 10;
let b = 15;
[ a, b ] = [ a+10, b+10 ]
console.log(a, b);        //=> 20 25
```

Which is also one statement, as well as being tidier and simpler to understand.

Comment: By the way, thanks a lot for the thought exercise, I absolutely love these kinds of things. Just made my night!

Comment: I was so close... Very nice! Too bad it isn't actually shorter than just using += twice for code golf.

Comment: Very nice I was thinking there had to be some mathematically way. To bad it doesn't work for strings too.

Answer (score 2):

> So in this case both a and b would end up being 7.

You can add the two defined variables and the specified incremented value multiplied by the number of variables then divide by the number of variables

```js
a = b = 5;
console.log(a, b);
n = 2;
a = b = ((a + b + n * 2) / 2);
console.log(a, b);
```

> something like var a=5,b=7; Then you want to add the result of
>   foo?2:3. So if false the result would be 8 and 10.

You can use destructuring assignment, `Array.prototype.map()`

```js
var a = 5, b = 7;
console.log(a, b);
var foo = false;
[a, b] = [a, b].map(v => v += foo ? 2 : 3);
console.log(a, b);
```