# Could any body tell me the purpose of this function?

Tags: pascal

```
procedure f(var a:integer; var b:integer);

    begin 

    a:=a xor b;
    b:=a xor b;
    a:=a xor b;

    end;
```

Comment: You should be able to figure this out yourself fairly quickly by "executing" it by hand.

Comment: `xor`: Exclusive or (xor) results in a value of true if and only if exactly one of the operands has a value of true. The rest of the code doesn't seem complicated so I'm not sure if I understand you correctly. Is it with the `xor` that you're struggling?

Comment: What a strange close-voting: twice *too broad* and twice *primarily opinion based*?

Comment: @onlyphantom *xor* is a btwise operator when the operands are integers

Comment: The question is perfectly valid and @SOROMEED is spot on.

Comment: The question's validity seems to arise from the procedure's name. I mean if it wasn't brilliantly named "f" I guess there would be no question to ask.

Comment: Why can't you just write a quick test app, call the function with two integer variables, and write the variables out after the call  to see what it does yourself?

Answer (score 3):

It's a common "trick" to swap the value of two variables (in this case: a, b) without using a third one.

See this topic (for C++, but it stands for any coding language) for a better and complete overview of the problem: [Swapping two variable value without using third variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1826159/swapping-two-variable-value-without-using-third-variable)