# Swap to parameters

Tags: c++

I am new to c++, and I've confronted with an unsolvable problem. I am writing a program to work with a large size CSV file and I need to do some specific operation, including swapping(for sorting). I've used following code, but I don't know it would be better to use a temporary variable.

```
template<typename T>
void swape(T& Par1, T&Par2)
{
Par1 = Par1+Par2;
Par2 = Par1 - Par2;
Par1 = Par1 - Par2;
}
```

I think it would probably be more computationally demanding rather than using temporary variable. I would appreciate, if any one could answer me, which one is better to use.

Sincerely.

Comment: You should take a look [in this SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1826159/swapping-two-variable-value-without-using-third-variable/1826183). It has a high chance being related to this question.

Comment: Why not use `std::swap`?

Comment: Why do you use this code if you doubt it? Are we looking at a https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem ?

Comment: the difference in performance and ram usage is so  small just do not worry about this and use std::swap

Comment: Take a look at the [godbolt decompilation](https://godbolt.org/z/s5rzWr)