# Assign value, but only if positive - without conditionals

Tags: java, math, integer, conditional-statements

### Question

I was impressed by tricks like the [xor-swap algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1826159/swapping-two-variable-value-without-using-third-variable/1826175) and similar. So I asked myself, is it possible to assign a variable a value, but only if the value is positive - without using any sort of `if` or hidden conditionals; just *pure math*.

### Alternative

Basically, this but without the `if`:

```java
int a = ...
int b = ...

if (b >= 0) {
    a = b;
}
```

### Examples

Here are some example input/output setups to illustrate the desired logic:

```java
a = 1, b = 10 -> a = 10 // b is positive
a = 1, b = 0 -> a = 0   // b is 0, also positive
a = 1, b = -10 -> a = 1 // b is negative
```

Answer (score 4):

### tl;dr

```java
int a = ...
int b = ...

int isNegative = b >>> 31;       // 1 if negative, 0 if positive
int isPositive = 1 - isNegative; // 0 if negative, 1 if positive
a = isPositive * b + isNegative * a;
```

### Signum

---

An easy way to achieve the task is to try to aquire some sort of [signum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sign_function), or more specifically a way to get a **factor** of

- either `0`, if `b` is **positive**
- or `1` if `b` is **negative**, or vice-versa.

Now, if you take a look at how `int` is represented internally with its 32-bits (this is called [Two's complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement)):

```java
// 1234
00000000 00000000 00000100 11010010
// -1234
11111111 11111111 11111011 00101110
```

You see that it has the so called **sign-bit** on the very left, the [most-significant-bit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bit_numbering#Most_significant_bit). Turns out, you can easily extract that bit with a simple bit-shift that just moves the whole bit-pattern `31` times to the right, only leaving the `32`-th bit, i.e. the sign-bit:

```java
int isNegative = b >>> 31; // 1 if negative, 0 if positive
```

Now, to get the opposite direction, you simply negate it and add `1` on top of it:

```java
int isPositive = 1 - isNegative; // 0 if negative, 1 if positive
```

---

### [Annihilator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Annihilator_(ring_theory)) and [Identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_element)

Once you have that, you can easily construct your desired value by exploiting the fact that

- multiplication with `0` basically erases the argument (`0` is an [annihilator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Annihilator_(ring_theory)) of `*`)
- and addition with `0` does not change the value (`0` is an [identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_element) element of `+`).

So, coming back to the logic we want to achieve in the first place:

- we want `b` if `b` is positive
- and we want `a` if `b` is negative

Hence, we just do `b * isPositive` and `a * isNegative` and add them together:

```java
a = isPositive * b + isNegative * a;
```

Now, if `b` is positive, you will get:

```java
a = 1 * b + 0 * a
  = b + 0
  = b
```

and if it is negative, you will get:

```java
a = 0 * b + 1 * a
  = 0 + a
  = a
```

---

### Other datatypes

The same approach can also be applied to any other signed data type, such as `byte`, `short`, `long`, `float` and `double`.

For example, here is a version for `double`:

```java
double a = ...
double b = ...

long isNegative = Double.doubleToLongBits(b) >>> 63;
long isPositive = 1 - isNegative;
a = isPositive * b + isNegative * a;
```

Unfortunately, in Java you can not use `>>>` directly on `double` (since it usually also makes no sense to mess up the exponent and mantissa), but therefore you have the helper [`Double#doubleToLongBits`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Double.html#doubleToLongBits(double)) which basically reinterprets the `double` as `long`.